Cross validation and MICE imputation
I'm working on a binary classification problem where I have some missing data. My initial idea was to use MiceForest. I'm also using stratified k fold technique (Data is imbalanced). I also want to minimize data leakage.

When should I impute missing values using MiceForest? For each fold? Or to the whole dataset in the beginning?
Should I use SMOTE to address class imbalance in each fold as I'm getting a lot of false positives (when using only stratified k fold without oversampling).
I get really good performance when I do mice imputation to the whole dataset, address class imbalance with smote and then do cross validations. I feel like this is overfitting? Is this because data leakage?


Can you please put your main question in the title? If you have multiple distinct questions, you should ask them in separate posts.

Is the imbalance really a problem in need of remedy? Statistics mostly says otherwise.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
